# Can one React Class Component be used with a table to create 2 web pages

Tags: reactjs

On my older repository that uses class components I have created a new branch https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/classiccruiseships-one-evo-table-with-joins.

The aim of this branch is to do the evolution part for classic cruise ships on 2 pages http://localhost:3000/evolution-part1 and http://localhost:3000/evolution-part2) , but with one [seeds evo](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/classiccruiseships-one-evo-table-with-joins/seeds/evo.js) and [migration](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/classiccruiseships-one-evo-table-with-joins/migrations/20200619215514_evo.js) table that has joins.

id 1 to 6 are to be used for http://localhost:3000/evolution-part1 page and id 7 to 12 used for http://localhost:3000/evolution-part2 page

So far I have managed to get all ships displayed on one http://localhost:3000/evolution-part1 page , with 2 paragraphs below this, as shown below.

My components can be found [here](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/classiccruiseships-one-evo-table-with-joins/client/components), but at the moment, I am wanting to get my Evolution.jsx component working with my ClassicShips.jsx component so that it can display the 2 pages.

In my Evolution component, how do I separate the 2 pages within [this.state](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/classiccruiseships-one-evo-table-with-joins/client/components/Evolution.jsx#L11) shown below ?

I have comments on using a variable shipsData , but how do I define it and separate evo1Data and evo2Data for the 2 pages ?

```
this.state = {
// later I will have to work out how the data can come from the correct table eg evo1 or evo2.
//initialize classicShip as false to allow for no data.
classicShips: false
// Maybe I need 2 data arrays here from the api call.
// This would separate ship data for the 2 evolution pages.
// Maybe I could have a variable called shipsData, this can be defined
// and separated with evo1Data for Evolution Part 1 and evo2Data for Evolution Part 2
// Here maybe have eg shipsData: evo1Data, shipsData: evo2Data
```

How does [this.setstate](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/classiccruiseships-one-evo-table-with-joins/client/components/Evolution.jsx#L37) know what id range to use for Part 1 or Part 2 ?

```
this.setState({
// Returns response from api
classicShips: res.evo
// Hopefully there is a way that I can separate Evolution Part 1 from Part 2
// So I can use id: 1 to 6 for Evolution Part 1 and id: 7 to 12 for Evolution Part 2
})
```

I just want to get an understanding on how I can make this work, any help that will make a difference will be much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: react is a single page technology.  so to create "2 pages" you need to manipulate the url your self and for "sharing" state you need to use a store like redux

Comment: Hi Jonathon,

How do you mean manipulate the url ?

I am getting the data from one evo table and it has to be separated into id 1 to 6 for  http://localhost:3000/evolution-part1 page and id 7 to 12 for http://localhost:3000/evolution-part2 page.

Are you also saying that using Redux, is the only way to handle the state for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

How exciting that your are writing about ships! :-)

I would suggest you either store your data in redux (https://redux.js.org/) or with the Context API (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Redux might be a bit overkill if this is the only data you need cross the platform.

Partial solution using Context:

```
<ShipContext.Provider value={ships}>{children}</ShipContext.Provider>
```

Then an idea is that you use the parameter option for react router. Instead of evolution-part1/2/... you could do evolution/1|2|3 etc and access that. (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params). Then you could do i.g

```
const ShipPage = () => {
  const { ships } = useShips() // Custom hooks using the ShipContext or whatever you want to use :-) Check the docs

  const { id } = useParams()

  const slicedShips = ships.slice(( id - 1 ) * 6, id * 6)

  return (
    <ShipsView ... /> 
  )
}
```

As a small side note on your project; it might be easier for you in the coming time to convert to functional components as this is more "the new". I posted a small example above.

Good luck! :-)

Comment: I will look into context and params for these Evolution pages

Actually I am doing this on my older repository which uses Class Components because  pages were displaying on this repository, so I just want to get it working here first.
The main end goal is to get it working with Functional Components and SASS for the CSS.
I actually have a newer repository that uses Functional React Components to do this , but I had problems with getting localhost working with functional components, at some stage I will have to get this working.
 
Thanks very much for the help Thomas.

Comment: @RobWilkinson Hi! Hope it helps. As a side suggestion you should check out Styled Components for your styling. If you consider this an answer to your question it would be great if you marked it as such! :-) Merry christmas!